# how to auto move next character in Jlabel using netbeans

Tags: java, arrays, swing, netbeans

I am creating a small application . In this application I have a Jlabel, jTextField1 and jButton. I have Array String calling ***st***. I have some letters in Array String. When the application run and click on jButton it is showing next letter of the array in Jlabel1 and it is running properly. When it is reaching last array of the string and then it is showing 2nd letter of that array and ***not showing 1st letter of the array*** as well as showing some error message in output. The Error message is ***Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 6***

My code is as follows:

```
String st[]={"a","b","c","d","e","f"};
    int i=0; 
 private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                             // TODO add your handling code here:
    if(i>=st.length)
    i=0;
      jTextField1.setText(st[i]);
       i++;
      jLabel1.setText(st[i]);
    }
```

Comment: You want all characters to be in separate line on label otherwise you have to user a characters which can split the string.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Place the counter reset after the increment statement:

```
i++;
if(i == st.length) i = 0;
```